# How do you "evolve" a weapon?

Tags: vampire-survivors

There are separate achievements to evolve eight weapons:

- Magic Wand
- Whip
- Knife
- Axe
- Cross
- King Bible
- Fire Wand
- Garlic

How do I "evolve" the weapons?

Comment: There's now 10 achievements for upgrading weapons

Answer (score 4):

To evolve weapons, you have to select the support item that matches with the weapon type, get the weapon to max level (you do not have to max out the support item), then the next chest will contain an evolved version of the weapon.

- Magic Wand + Empty Tome becomes "Holy Wand", which constantly fires magic with no delay
- Whip + Hollow Heart becomes "Bloody Tear" which deals more damage and has lifesteal
- Knife + Bracer becomes "Thousand Edge" which constantly fires knives with no delay
- Axe + Candelabrador becomes "Death Spiral" which goes through enemies.
- Cross + Clover becomes "Heaven Sword" which can randomly deal critical damage
- King Bible + Spellbinder becomes "Unholy Vespers" which makes the bibles never stop
- Fire Wand + Spinach becomes "Hellfire" which passes through multiple enemies
- Garlic + Pummarola becomes "Soul Eater", which increases power when recovering HP
- Holy Water + Attractorb becomes "La Borra", which makes the AOE fields huge and follow you.

Additionally there is another upgrade that works a little differently.

Peachone + Ebonywings are both weapons rather than a weapon and support item. If you max out BOTH weapons, you can upgrade them into a single weapon and regain a weapon slot (and unlock an achievement).